# Physical System Producing Prime Numbers?

Tags: analysis, prime-numbers, mathematical-physics

Have you seen this wonderful movie "Contact" starring Jodie Foster ? She is basically looking for signals from outer space to discover intelligent life. She eventually finds a source that transmits the sequence of prime numbers and this is considered as an answer to her questions. Everyone is convinced that the signal came from conscious, intelligent beings.

My question as a mathematician is, is this absolutely true ? Can we have a non-intelligent physical system producing prime numbers ? I understand that I haven't actually defined the word "intelligent" and that's because it is very hard (if not impossible) to define at this point.

This is some form of Turing test, no?

It could be a program on a computer that does this but then some intelligent life form must have manufactured the computer and coded up the program so are we back to square one ?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: For a similar question, see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43397/examples-of-prime-numbers-in-nature). For example, flowers involve prime numbers and Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Thanks, interesting!

Comment: I believe there are seven-year, eleven-year, thirteen-year, and seventeen-year locusts (actually cicadas), but not 12-, 14-, 15-, or 16-year locusts, for reasons relating to the greater survival value of a prime-length reproductive cycle.

Comment: There is a hypothetical connection between primes and dynamical systems via zeros of $\zeta(s).$ There are several answers on this site or you can google it. It's also discussed in *Prime Obsession* by Derbyshire.